# ipad dev - in the UISplitViewController template, how is the method setDetailItem called?

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am developing an ipad app which has a UISplitViewController. (I use IB to build the interface, but I do not use the template) Both master and detail (left and right) views are navigationController. The left view subclass UITableView and the right view should push another controller if the cell on the left is selected. I don't know how to make my detail view responds to my master view.

Also, in the template, the detailViewController has a id detailItem and a method setDetailItem. How are these two connected? I cannot see any connection between but setDetailItem is called when detailViewController.detailItem is being called.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,

We had a similar question and found that DetailItem is a property.  Check out our blog for more information.
http://totalintmobile.tumblr.com/post/2623272838/what-calls-setdetailitem-in-uisplitview-template